# How can I fix the output problem in my code?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code to print out true or false depending on whether the value goes below zero or not. Here is my code

```
    L = [10,10,10]
init_hp = 0
def is_dead(L: list[int], init_hp:int):
    if init_hp == 0:
        return True
    elif sum(L) + init_hp > 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
print(is_dead(L,init_hp))
```

However, for the `L: list` I want to make sure that the output prints out True if the value has gone below zero already. For example, if `L: list = [2,-3,5]`, I want to make sure that the output prints out `True`, because 2+(-3), the first two variables, already return a negative number,"-1", EVEN THOUGH THE END RESULT IS POSITIVE... however using my code, that doesn't work, what code should I use to make sure that it will print true if a scenario like this happens

Comment: You can use for loop for that.

Comment: can you please explain how? I've been trying but I dont think I'm putting it in the right place...

Comment: Yup, I'm doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loop and iterate all numbers in the list.

```
L = [10, 10, 10]
init_hp = 0
def is_dead(L: list[int], init_hp:int):
    if init_hp == 0:
        return True
    v = 0
    for num in L:
        if v+num < 0:
            return True
        v += num
    
    if init_hp+v < 0:
         return True
    return False

print(is_dead(L,init_hp))
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for helping, is there a shorter method to do this?. Your code works and its brilliant! but I would like to keep it as short as I can, is that possible?

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: I am pretty sure that the last check (`if init_hp + v < 0:`) is unnecessary

Comment: @Matiiss, in the question the asker checks if `init_hp` plus the sum of `L` is greater than 0 or not.

Comment: so? I am pretty sure that if `init_hp` is negative or equal 0 it should be dead (I mean op checks strictly for hp being 0 but I am pretty sure that negative hp would mean that whatever it is is dead) so the last check should never become true anyways because as the loop before checks `v` is positive and since `init_hp` should be positive too, it will never evaluate that if statement to True and thus won't ever return `True` from that if statement, tho we have to ask @Bruffff whether initial negative hp is acceptable

Comment: and btw `if True in [True for num in L if v+num < 0]:` can be shortened to `if [True for num in L if v+num < 0]:` but now I am not entirely sure which part that even checks since you haven't clarified and it doesn't take sums, did you test it out?

Comment: Oh, yes. Then the line of my code might not be necessary

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way I could think of was to use `itertools.accumulate`:

```py
from typing import List
from itertools import accumulate


def is_dead(lst: List[int], i_hp: int):
    if i_hp == 0:
        return True
    for total in accumulate(lst):
        if total < 0:
            return True
    return False


print(is_dead([2, -3, 5], 1))
# True
print(is_dead([10, 10, 10], 1))
# False
```

Or slightly shorter (but also may be slightly less memory efficient):

```py
def is_dead(lst: List[int], i_hp: int):
    if i_hp == 0:
        return True
    if [True for total in accumulate(lst) if total < 0]:
        return True
    return False
```

Sources:

- [`itertools.accumulate` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the numbers and check whether the sum is less than zero or not.

```
def is_dead(L: list[int], init_hp: int):
    if init_hp <= 0:
        return True

    s = 0
    for num in L:
        s += num
        if s < 0:
            return True

    return False  # sum > 0


# Test cases:
print(is_dead([2, -3, 5], 1))  # True
print(is_dead([10, 10, 10], -1))  # True
print(is_dead([10, 10, 10], 1))  # False
```